# Install from source in Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need to install `graph-tool` from source, so I add in my Dockerfile this:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN git clone https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool.git
RUN cd graph-tool && ./configure && make && make install
```

as it written [here](https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/wikis/Installation-instructions#manual-compilation).

When I try to build my Docker-compose I catch a error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: ./configure: not found
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

ADDED Full Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV C_FORCE_ROOT true

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y git \
    && apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev \
    && apt-get install -y binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin \
    && cd /usr/local/bin \
    && ln -s /usr/bin/python3 python \
    && pip3 install --upgrade pip

RUN git clone https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool.git

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libboost-all-dev

RUN apt update && apt install -y --no-install-recommends \
    make \
    build-essential \
    g++

RUN cd graph-tool && ./configure && make && make install

# Project specific setups
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD . /code
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: When you run `docker build`, it will print out a hex number after each step; that is a valid Docker image ID and you can `docker run --rm -it 0123456789abc sh` to see what came out of it.  Once you're in that shell, you can try running `./configure` by hand and debug it further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run **autogen.sh** first, it will generate **configure** file

P.S. Make sure you install libtool

```
apt-get install libtool
```

Comment: already installed, reinstalled and still the same - didn't work

Comment: I've edited my answer.

You can also refere to this wiki page, and install it from the repository, unless you really need to compile it from source,

https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/wikis/installation-instructions#debian-ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

You have to install the prerequisites first.

```
RUN apt update && apt install -y --no-install-recommends \
    make \
    build-essential \
    g++ \
    ....
```

Don't forget to clean up and remove temp/unnecessary files!